# Create a table of data by month with totals

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 database tables, joined on a FK (ResponseHeader) examples below (date is 6 October in the example)

ResponseHeader

```
ResponseHeaderId                        DateTime
0e24cf96-81eb-2122-7e4a-0d200474692f    06/10/2018 11:15:59
```

ResponseData

```
ResponseDataId                          ResponseHeaderId                        Response
41c831f1-0adc-2bd5-053e-00406fa526b6    0e24cf96-81eb-2122-7e4a-0d200474692f    1   
78967068-82a6-4098-ba35-03211a923f46    0e24cf96-81eb-2122-7e4a-0d200474692f    2
854bc8a6-5877-a6fb-9072-00e358323350    0e24cf96-81eb-2122-7e4a-0d200474692f    2   
fe2a667d-ca0e-49a6-b330-f4d4232bfe89    0e24cf96-81eb-2122-7e4a-0d200474692f    3
30f0270e-3e69-3408-7add-02a85f4b9aeb    0e24cf96-81eb-2122-7e4a-0d200474692f    1
```

There are multiple ResponseHeaders and each response header has 5 rows of data each)

The responses for each group of response data needs to be added up (example = 9)

What I want to achieve though is a table like this where everything is totalled by Month for the given year set.

```
2018
Month        Responses        Sum
October      1                9
```

But, as there are multiple rows for each Responseheader, what I eventually want is this:

```
2018
Month        Responses        Sum
October      185              234
September    564              985
...
2017
Month        Responses        Sum
January      54               123
...
```

I've got linq for summing by month, for example:

```
var total = 0;
var filteredResponses = Model.SurveyResponseHeader.Where(x => x.StartDate > DateTime.Today.LastMonth() && x.StartDate > DateTime.Today.AddMonths(1).LastMonth()).ToList();

foreach (var response in filteredResponses)
{
    var responseTotal = (response.SurveyResponses.Sum(x => x.Response));
    total += responseTotal;
}

@total
```

Given all this, how do I?

- Loop through the data by month, summing each response set of data for the month
- Group the data by month and year

I have no problem with some basic linq and C# for querying data by dates and summing, but grouping and summing like this is a bit beyond me

Comment: I'm not sure what the actual question is here

Comment: You make a good point, I haven't actually said... I don't know how to write the code to generate this output. I've tried, but I can't work it out

Comment: Your question seems a bit too broad.  Can you focus it to a single aspect that you're having trouble with?  E.g. "How do I loop through months?" or "How do I create columns?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();

            dt1.Columns.Add("ResponseHeaderId", typeof (string));
            dt1.Columns.Add("DateTime", typeof (DateTime));

            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "0e24cf96-81eb-2122-7e4a-0d200474692f", DateTime.Parse("06/10/2018 11:15:59") });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "0e24cf96-81eb-2122-7e4a-0d2004746930", DateTime.Parse("05/10/2018 11:15:59") });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "0e24cf96-81eb-2122-7e4a-0d2004746931", DateTime.Parse("04/10/2018 11:15:59") });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "0e24cf96-81eb-2122-7e4a-0d2004746932", DateTime.Parse("03/10/2017 11:15:59") });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "0e24cf96-81eb-2122-7e4a-0d2004746933", DateTime.Parse("02/10/2017 11:15:59") });

            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

            dt2.Columns.Add("ResponseDataId", typeof (string));
            dt2.Columns.Add("ResponseHeaderId", typeof (string));
            dt2.Columns.Add("Response", typeof (int));


            dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { "41c831f1-0adc-2bd5-053e-00406fa526b6","0e24cf96-81eb-2122-7e4a-0d200474692f", 1 });  
            dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { "78967068-82a6-4098-ba35-03211a923f46","0e24cf96-81eb-2122-7e4a-0d200474692f", 2 });
            dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { "854bc8a6-5877-a6fb-9072-00e358323350","0e24cf96-81eb-2122-7e4a-0d2004746930", 2 });
            dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { "fe2a667d-ca0e-49a6-b330-f4d4232bfe89","0e24cf96-81eb-2122-7e4a-0d2004746931", 3 });
            dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { "30f0270e-3e69-3408-7add-02a85f4b9aeb","0e24cf96-81eb-2122-7e4a-0d2004746932", 1 });
            dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { "30f0270e-3e69-3408-7add-02a85f4b9aeb","0e24cf96-81eb-2122-7e4a-0d2004746933", 1 });


            var join = (from d1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                        join d2 in dt2.AsEnumerable() on d1.Field<string>("ResponseHeaderId") equals d2.Field<string>("ResponseHeaderId")
                        select new { d1 = d1, d2 = d2 })
                        .OrderByDescending(x => x.d1.Field<DateTime>("DateTime"))
                       .GroupBy(x => new { year = x.d1.Field<DateTime>("DateTime").Year, month = x.d1.Field<DateTime>("DateTime").ToString("MMMM") })
                       .Select(x => new { year = x.Key.year, month = x.Key.month, total = x.Select(y => y.d2.Field<int>("Response")).Sum()})
                       .ToList();
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @jdweng  With some adjustment to my models I've got exactly what I needed.